# Rails 3 user session gets destroyed while calling create from backbone collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have a backbone app which is being fed data by a Rails backend.
When trying to call create from Backbone collection, the session in rails gets destroyed.
Any pointers on how to overcome it?

Comment: This would help
http://www.ngauthier.com/2011/02/backbone-and-rails-forgery-protection.html

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is almost always a result of a bad or non-existent [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) token. In recent versions of Rails 3.0.4+, any request that doesn't have a CSRF token that matches the token generated for the users current session will destroy the session as a security measure.

Here is some more info on CSRF security in Rails:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

You can easily test to see if this is what is causing your problem by commenting out the `protect_from_forgery` method call (probably in your `application_controller.rb` file). But I wouldn't recommend disabling it permanently for security reasons.