# AJAX calls with rescue_from in Rails ApplicationController session seems to be lost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

In Rails I have added a couple rescue_from handlers in the ApplicationController. They work fine except for looks like the session gets lost because the next request is always being redirected to login page.

ApplicationController:

```
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :handle_record_not_found
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, :with => :handle_record_invalid
  rescue_from ApplicationSecurityError, :with => :handle_security_error
  rescue_from ApplicationError, :with => :handle_application_error
```

One of the handlers:

```
def handle_application_error(error)
  logger.warn "#{error.class} #{error.user_safe_message} #{error.debug_info}, user #{@current_user.id}"
  render :json => {:errors => {:base => error.user_safe_message}, :status => :ok}
end
```

Is there a way to use these handlers without losing session?
I checked in Firebug and it's definitely server side, because jQuery gets a different cookie from that erroneous request which is shorter than previous so i think i do lose the session.

Comment: You may need to be a bit more specific. Under what circumstances do you see the problem? If it's an Ajax request, are you including the CSRF token?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I was not including them. I did POST requests with _method:'put' specified to update an object. There was a mention of jQuery.ajax before I edited my question. Oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I did another try on SO search and found
[Rails 3 user session gets destroyed while calling create from backbone collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353118/rails-3-user-session-gets-destroyed-while-calling-create-from-backbone-collection)

which pointed to `protect_from_forgery` which took me to [My jquery AJAX POST requests works without sending an Authenticity Token (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059483/my-jquery-ajax-post-requests-works-without-sending-an-authenticity-token-rails)

To fix the problem I just added that forgery protection parameters to all my AJAX requests.

```
var _auth_token_name = '<%= request_forgery_protection_token %>';
var _auth_token = '<%= form_authenticity_token %>';
```

The request body construction (which I use to call `$.ajax`) starts with this:

```
var data = {};
data[_auth_token_name] = _auth_token;
```